# Stored procedure which has multiple parameters but I can insert which I want

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Update_User]
    @usr_ID int,
    @usr_Name nvarchar(50),
    @usr_Username nvarchar(25),
    @usr_Password nvarchar(25),
    @usr_CNIC nvarchar(15),
    @usr_Phone nvarchar(13),
    @usr_Address nvarchar(100),
    @usr_DateTime datetime,
    @usr_Role_FK int,
    @usr_Status bit
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE tbl_Users
    SET usr_Name = @usr_Name,
        usr_Username = @usr_Username,
        usr_Password = @usr_Password,
        usr_CNIC = @usr_CNIC,
        usr_Phone = @usr_Phone,
        usr_Address = @usr_Address,
        usr_DateTime = @usr_DateTime,
        usr_Role_FK = @usr_Role_FK,
        usr_Status = @usr_Status
    WHERE usr_ID = @usr_ID
END
```

My C# code:

```
Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
ht.Add("@usr_Name", txtFullName.Text);
ht.Add("@usr_Username", txtUsername.Text);
ht.Add("@usr_Password", txtPassword.Text);
ht.Add("@usr_CNIC", txtCNIC.Text);
ht.Add("@usr_Phone", txtPhone.Text);
ht.Add("@usr_Address", txtAddress.Text);
ht.Add("@usr_DateTime", System.DateTime.Now);
ht.Add("@usr_Role_FK", Convert.ToInt32(DDRoles.SelectedValue.ToString()));
ht.Add("@usr_Status", DDStatus.SelectedIndex);
Model.MainClass.LetsCRUD("sp_Insert_User", ht);
```

`LetsCRUD` code:

```
public static int LetsCRUD(string procedureName, Hashtable ht)
{
    int result = 0;

    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(procedureName, con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        foreach (DictionaryEntry item in ht)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(item.Key.ToString(), item.Value);
        }

        con.Open();
        result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        con.Close();
        ShowMSG(ex.Message, "Error", "Error");
    }

    return result;
}
```

Problem is I want to use the same logic and code in the update time and just want to update only one column and not want to pass all the values again, but when I pass on one value, I get errors.

So now this time I only want to update my phone number

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: thank you so much in future i will always not use it. Really thank you

Comment: related - don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use NULL as default for the input parameters.
The downside is that it is a bit cumbersome when you really need to update values to NULL (you could workaround that with other default values or translating other values to NULL, eg. an emtpy string or 0 means NULL, it depends on your case)

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Update_User]
    @usr_ID int, --@user_id mandatory
    @usr_Name nvarchar(50) = null, --default:: unknown
    @usr_Username nvarchar(25) = null, --default::unknown
    @usr_Password nvarchar(25) = null,
    @usr_CNIC nvarchar(15) = null,
    @usr_Phone nvarchar(13) = null,
    @usr_Address nvarchar(100) = null,
    @usr_DateTime datetime = null,
    @usr_Role_FK int = null,
    @usr_Status bit = null
AS
BEGIN
    --check if all input params are null
    if not exists
    (
        select @usr_Name, @usr_Username, @usr_Password, @usr_CNIC, @usr_Phone, @usr_Address, @usr_DateTime, @usr_Role_FK, @usr_Status
        except
        select null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null
    )
    begin
            --no need for an update, everything is null
            return;
    end

    --at least one param is not null, perform the update 
    UPDATE tbl_Users
    SET usr_Name = isnull(@usr_Name, usr_Name),
        usr_Username = isnull(@usr_Username, usr_Username),
        usr_Password = isnull(@usr_Password, usr_Password),
        usr_CNIC = @usr_CNIC,--same here, isnull...
        usr_Phone = @usr_Phone,--same here....
        usr_Address = @usr_Address,--same here...
        usr_DateTime = @usr_DateTime,--same here...
        usr_Role_FK = @usr_Role_FK, --same here...
        usr_Status = isnull(@usr_Status, usr_Status)
    WHERE usr_ID = @usr_ID;
END
```

Comment: so you mean to say while update only one value this method will not update the other values?

Comment: the final result will be only one changed value, behind the scenes all other values/columns are updated to their existing ones.

Comment: And if there is an update trigger, it will look like every single column has been modified. Be careful with this method. Encouraging laziness of app developers can lead to problems. What happens when someone wants to "remove" a value - like phone number. How does the GUI handle that and what effect should it have in the table?